# asp.net not able to load css3 pie

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, css3pie

I tried every possible way to provide path of PIE.js, i am using asp.net, the same used to work in java+tomcat. I tried giving like this

1)Files:
**css/home.css**,
**css/pie/PIE.js**

in home.css behavior: url('pie/PIE.js');

not working

2)Files:
**css/home.css**,
**css/PIE.js**

in home.css behavior: url('PIE.js');

still not working

Someone help please.

Thanks

Comment: 2)Files: css/home.css, css/PIE. 

behavior: url(css/PIE.js);

Comment: U mean i should remove '' and y url(css/PIE.js) when PIE.js is with home.css in css folder

Comment: No just keep your css file and pie.js file in your css folder and and behavior: url(css/PIE.js) in your css class.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `PIE.htc` in css or include `PIE.js` in your html? Read more about using PIE [here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: If the way what i am using is wrong, then how it worked in java+tomcat? can u explain

Comment: Sorry, but I know nothing about java.

Comment: i think java has nothing to do with this. Ofcourse not, its the problem of webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You add the htc file to behavior

Example:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  behavior:url("/Library/CSS3PIE/PIE.htc");
}
```